# Weird Texture paiting glich

Tags: uv, texture-painting

i was texture paiting donut and some weird glitches happened:   this pattern isnt dissapearing when i paint it down again.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could show the UV-map, as i believe there might be some problem with that.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f0573eb33a2815c35dff89d91f50d07e
Yes indeed sth wrong, but i cant delet those vertices on the map

Comment: You can't delete vertices in the UV-Map, as they represent those from the mesh, but i'd suggest to select an edge loop along the outer middle marked a seam and maybe one on the inside. Then uv-unwrap and you should have a clean UV-Map and can paint without the weird issue.

Comment: Yes that indeed helped, i forgot to respond. I've done whole sceen :)
https://gyazo.com/662705ca1a48e8689539386f54812fc7

Comment: Glad it helped and you have one nice project under your belt, i know it feels good to finish a project, congrats ;)